# Memset function in programm that resolves host adresses

Tags: c, memset

First of all, i understand what the code (see at the end of the post) does in general and i dont want an overall explanation.

What i don't understand is this particular line of code:
**memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));**

What i get so far is that a *memset()* is a function to fill the string which it is pointed to up.

It has three parameters, first the pointer to the string, second the value to be set and third the number of bytes set to the value.

In this case the the value to be filled up is *&hints* which would be the adress of the variable hints. The value which should be set is 0 so it is filled with zeroes. And last it is filled to the size of the struct addrinfo.

So in this case *memset()* generates for the variable hints zeroes to the size of the struct. Did i get this right?

If yes, why is this needed in my example?

```
#include <stdlib.h>/* EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <stdio.h>/* printf */
#include <string.h>/* memset() */
#include <errno.h>/* int errno */
#include <sys/types.h>/* socket defines */
#include <sys/socket.h>/* socket() */
#include <netdb.h>/* getaddrinfo() */
#define ECHO_PORT "7"

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
if (argc != 2) {
printf ("Usage: %s HOSTNAME\n", argv[0]);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Resolve host addresses: */

struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo* result, *rp;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;/* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;/* Stream socket */
hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;/* Any protocol */

int err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], ECHO_PORT, &hints, &result);

/* Handle potential error: */

if (err) {
printf("Error: getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(err));
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Print names found: */

printf("Addresses for %s:\n", argv[1]);
for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
int af = rp->ai_family;
char* address = NULL;
int ok;

if (AF_INET == rp->ai_family) {
uint8_t in_addr =((struct sockaddr_in*)rp->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
address = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
ok = inet_ntop(af, &in_addr, address, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
}

if (AF_INET6 == rp->ai_family) {
char* in6_addr =((struct sockaddr_in6*)rp->ai_addr)->sin6_addr.s6_addr;
address = malloc(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
ok = inet_ntop(af, in6_addr, address, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
}

if (ok) {
printf("%s\n", address);
}
else {
perror("inet_ntop");
}

free(address);
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Do you know that uninitialised variables have indeterminate values by default? The point of the memset here is to ensure that object doesn't, and hence any fields that might not be set have zero values - instead of garbage that would be undefined behaviour to read. If those 4 assignments cover all the fields in the struct, then technically the memset is redundant - but it's probably good practice, since it might get more fields later and then something could blow up if the struct weren't zeroed out first and someone later tried to read an uninitialised member. Btw C++ has better way to do that

Comment: Please do not tag both C and C++ except for questions that involve interactions or differences between the two languages. The answer to questions may be different for C and C++, and that can be confusing. To ask the same question for C and for C++, enter two separate questions. Since your code appears to be C code, I am deleting the C++ tag. If you are using C++ and not C, then you can change the tag.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree -  and I had to change my C++ -only answer :-)

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the background information. I did not know that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you for the hint. I will consider this in future posts

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry i caused you trouble. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @lobster :-) You didn't cause me any trouble at all. Glad to help and you're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is basically correct.  The code is simply filling the entire `hints` variable with `0x00` bytes before passing it to `getaddrinfo()`.  This is needed to initialize the `hints` to a default state, which is important because `addrinfo` contains flags and memory pointers to control `getaddrinfo()`'s behavior.  So you can't just leave the `hints` in an uninitialized state, it will contain random garbage that will cause *undefined behavior*, confusing `getaddrinfo()` and/or even leading to corrupted memory, crashes, etc.

Using the `memset()` is a quick way to initialize all of the fields of the `hints` to zeros in one quick operation, instead of initializing each field individually.  This way, you can focus on assigning values to just the fields you are actually interested in.

An easier way to initialize the `hints` is like this instead:

```c
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
```

This will *value-initialize* the first field (`ai_flags`) to 0, and *default-initialize* the remaining fields to their default values, which in this case is also zeros.

Comment: And of course, "older compilers" include not only those implementing old versions of C++, but also all C compilers that do not provide extensions to initializer syntax.

Comment: The question is now tagged as C. `= {}` is not preferred way of initialization in *any* language.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you understood it correctly.

It's needed in the code below because in

```
struct addrinfo hints;
```

`hints` is left uninitialized and the programmer wanted to make sure all the fields a zeroed.

An easier solution would be to initialize it directly:

```
addrinfo hints{}; // C++11 and later

struct addrinfo hints = {0}; /* C and C++ */
```

and skip `memset`.

Another option is to initialize it with the correct values using [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) (C99 and C++20). In C you can specify the fields out-of-order, but not in C++, so this order would work in both:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {  /* "struct" not needed in C++ */
    .ai_flags    = 0,
    .ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC,
    .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
    /* .ai_protocol and the rest will be zeroed */
};
```

For older standards without designated initializers:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {
    0,
    AF_UNSPEC,
    SOCK_STREAM
};
```

Comment: The C version of the initializer needs at least one value.  `{ 0 }` would be idiomatic.  I'm uncertain whether C++ accepts that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger C++ accepts that fine too, so I'll add that, thanks.

Comment: Note that `{}` will work in C++11 and later only, but `{0}` will work in all C++ versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, yeah, better make a note of that too, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that `memset` is being used here to set all bytes of `hints` to zero.

This is being done so that any field that is not explicitly set later has the value 0.  Because `hints` is uninitialized, its fields have indeterminate values, so doing this sets all fields to 0.  If you look at the definition of `struct addrinfo`:

```
       struct addrinfo {
           int              ai_flags;
           int              ai_family;
           int              ai_socktype;
           int              ai_protocol;
           socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
           struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
           char            *ai_canonname;
           struct addrinfo *ai_next;
       };
```

You can see that the program only explicitly sets the first 4 fields.  The call to `memset` first takes care of the rest.